# How can I specify the image_id in an ASG but use the existing launch template to provide all the pre-set details for networking?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I would like to use an existing launch template (LT) in my auto scaling group. The LT defines some networking properties but allows the instance type and ami to be chosen at launch as we have different Ami's depending on the purpose.

The example below uses a `mixed_instances_policy` with an override...

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "filebeat-asg" {
  depends_on = [ data.aws_launch_template.filebeat-launch ]
  min_size = 0
  max_size = 5

  name = "${var.environment_name}_filebeat-asg"

  mixed_instances_policy {
    launch_template {
      launch_template_specification {
        launch_template_id = data.aws_launch_template.filebeat-launch.id
      }

      override {
        instance_type = "m5.large"
        image_id = var.ecs_ami
      }
    }
  }

  vpc_zone_identifier = [data.aws_subnet.selected.id]

  instance_refresh {
    strategy = "Rolling"
    preferences {
      min_healthy_percentage = 50
    }
  }

  tag {
    key                 = "Purpose"
    value               = var.environment_name
    propagate_at_launch = true
  }
}
```

However this gives the following error

```
Error: Unsupported argument

  on modules/ecs/main.tf line 29, in resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "filebeat-asg":
  29:         image_id = var.ecs_ami

An argument named "image_id" is not expected here.
```

If I take this out I get the original problem

```
Error: Error creating Auto Scaling Group: ValidationError: You must use a valid fully-formed launch template. The request must contain the parameter ImageId
    status code: 400, request id: 56328939-44d9-4fb5-b3ed-89fc35435d81
```

The problem I have is that only some of the values are pre-baked into the launch template. This way we can impose the launch template to control where an instance is run (for example) but not restrict the ami or instance type.

ASG have the capability for overrides which I have used to set the `instance_type` however it doesn't seem to work for `image_id`.

Is there a way to specify the image_id in the ASG resource?